# Bootstrap carousel isn't working on remote server

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm developing a landing page for a [website](http://www.roughnough.com) with a background bootstrap carousel. Everything worked ok on my local development server, but since I  uploaded it to the remote server the bootstrap carousel stopped working there. There are no errors in the console and all resources seems to be loading in the correct order, so I can't understand why the carousel is broken in the remote server. Any guess?

Thanks,

Comment: can give your page link?

Comment: Hi! Rui, can you show your that part of the javascript that triggers carousel on page load???

Comment: Can you access the images in the browser? e.g. www.roughnough.com/images/slider1.png

Comment: No real way for us to help other than guesswork without seeing your code.

Comment: Please include more code in this question, don't just post links.. otherwise it's no help to future visitors.  the HTML, JS and CSS snippets that form the carousel would be a good start!  :)

Comment: I'm sorry for you all. The website was up before I posted this thread, so you could check all the code. Don't know what happened in the meantime. Anyway, I will try to post my code here later today. Thanks =)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The page is back online at www.roughnough.com if any of you want to have a look at it. 
Here is an abstraction of what I have on the page. I'm using Angular 1.1.4, Bootstrap 3 and Jquery 2.1.
Hope this helps.

Index Page

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Index Page</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/css/style.css">

</head>

<body>

    <div id="view" ng-view></div>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/css/bootstrap-modal-bs3patch.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/css/bootstrap-modal.css">

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/js/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/js/angular-translate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app/js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="app/js/main.js"></script>
    <script> Google Analytics script </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Home View

```
<div class="fill background-img">
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('app/img/1.jpg');">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('app/img/2.jpg');">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('app/img/3.jpg');">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('app/img/4.jpg');">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('app/img/5.jpg');">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('app/img/6.jpg');">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="front-logo-mask fill">
    <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('app/img/Logo_Mask.png');">

    </div>
</div>

</html>
```

main.js

```
$(window).load(function() {        

        $('.carousel').carousel({
            interval: 3000,
            wrap: true,
        });

});
```

Comment: hmm... Another piece of the puzzle. Probably just some problem with Chrome. I've tried to open the website in Safari and Firefox, and it works well. Wondering why the bug in Chorme.. I'm currently using version 33.0.1750.146